# Entity Framework 4: Selecting Single Record

Tags: entity-framework, select, entity-framework-4, record

I'm currently planning on switching my "manual query-writing" code to a nice SQL framework, so I can leave the queries or sql things to the framework, instead of writing the queries myself.

Now I'm wondering how I can get a single record from my table in Entity Framework 4?

I've primarily used SQL like `SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE Id = {1}`. That doesn't work in EF4, as far as I'm concerned.

Is there a way I can select a single ID-Based record from my Context?

Something like:

```
public Address GetAddress(int addressId)
{
    var result = from Context.Addresses where Address.Id = addressId;

    Address adr = result as Address;

    return Address;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I would use "Context.Addresses.Find(id)"  (faster in writing and execution!)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
var address = Context.Addresses.First(a => a.Id == addressId);
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I then access the "address" values? Can I simply cast it to "Address" and enter it via address.Id, address.Property1? Or do I need to do something like address["Id"] or address["Property1"]?

Comment: Yes, simply you can access property value of Address class via 'int id = address.Id'

Comment: Okay, so there is no need to cast it to type "Address"? Sweet. Thank you!

Comment: You can use address.Foo, address.Bar etc.

Comment: I would also consider using FirstOrDefault method. To not have an exception (expensive), but rather null "object".

Comment: @SeToY: var is just a shortcut instead of entering the type explicitly. The compiler will figure out that address is of type `Address` by knowing the return type of `Context.Addresses...`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Single` or `First` methods.

The difference between those methods is that Single expects a single row and throws an exception if it doesn't have a single row.

The usage is the same for both of them

Comment: Single and SingleOrDefault are actually supported at the top of the query since EF 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

(Based on VS 2015) If you create an .edmx (Add --> ADO.NET Entity Data Model).
[image]

Go through the steps to created the ".edmx" and use the following to run the stored procedure. `emailAddress` is the parameter you are passing to the stored procedure `g_getLoginStatus`. This will pull the first row into `LoginStatus` and `status` is a column in the database:

```
bool verasity = false;
DBNameEntities db = new DBNameEntities();   // Use name of your DBEntities

var LoginStatus = db.g_getLoginStatus(emailAddress).FirstOrDefault();

if ((LoginStatus != null) && (LoginStatus.status  == 1))
{
      verasity = true;
}
```