# Select required include tables in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I am working with EF on a normalised database.

For my Offers entity I have the following table structure:

### Offers

plus either:

### PostType

Offers_SitePost or Offers_CommunityPost

plus either:

### OfferType

Offers_VoucherCode or Offers_Deal or Offers_Sale

So a complete offer will be made up of a definite entry in Offers plus an entry in one of the PostType tables and an entry in one of the OfferType tables.

I know from the offers table, which of the other tables should contain data. I'm using properties like IsSitePost to do this.

I'm trying to work out the best way of getting just the necessary data, for both a single offer and a list of offers. Obviously I can include all tables but I doubt this will work out to be the most efficient.

Here's the code I'm working on for a single offer:

```
    public static Offer GetById2(int ID)
    {
        ID.ThrowDefault("ID");

        var r = new CrudRepo<Offer>(Local.Items.Uow.Context);

        var offer = r.Find(o => o.OfferId == ID);

        // if is site post Include("SiteOffers")
        // else is community post Include("CommunityOffers") etc

        return offer.SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Can anyone offer advice as to the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to query DB for the offer you are looking for

look at this topic:
[Entity Framework 4: Selecting Single Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016178/entity-framework-4-selecting-single-record)

Comment: The link doesn't answer my question. I'm looking how to use IQueryable to return specific Include() tables for both a single item and a list of items.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put your .Include prior to the find as include extends the underlying table source, not the object type. This is also dependent on how you are implementing the CrudRepo and what it is returning to know if your repository knows how to handle Include itself.

```
public static Offer GetById2(int ID)
 {
     ID.ThrowDefault("ID");
      var r = new CrudRepo<Offer>(Local.Items.Uow.Context);
      if (IsSitePost)
         r = r.Include("SiteOffers");
      else
         r = r.Include("CommunityOffers");
      var offer = r.Find(o => o.OfferId == ID);
      return offer.SingleOrDefault();
 }
```

Comment: Jim, not quite there. I wont know the value of IsSitePost until data comes back in the line starting var offer, which returns iqueryable.