# How to increment a string primary key like AAAA-ENG-00001 when create a new object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the next function to insert an Engagement. How I have to retrieve the last record and increment its primary key?

```
public void InsertEngagement(Engagement eng)
{        
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(eng.Id))
    {
        eng.Id = DateTime.Today.Year + "ENG" + "-00001";
        _context.Engagement.Add(eng);
    }
    else
    {

    }
```

Comment: I don't know much about Entity Framework, but would it be possible to create a "NumberSeries" table that simply contains the current ID and its last part? A nifty Stored Procedure using an `UPDATE ... OUTPUT` could then create the new ID from the current year and the incremented last part.

Comment: Do this in a database trigger so you can briefly lock the last record or use a sequence (Oracle or Sql Server 2012).

Comment: Are you really sure this is what you want from a primary key?  If you're sure this is what you want, consider a 'sequence' table to manage the incremental values and override your DbContext SaveChanges to compute your id.  I would store the 3 components of your key as separate fields and add a DisplayName read-only property (or extension method to keep your poco's pure) to format as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I seggest you store the last value of the the entiger part of your primary key. And then, get it, use it, and increment it when needed.

```
public string GetNewIdValue()
{
    // Get the counter value
    int counter = getCounterFromDatabase();

    // Format the new id value
    var value = String.Format("{0}-Eng-{1}", DateTime.Now.Year, counter)

    return value;
}
```

After adding the engagement to the database, and if the operation was done correclty, increment the counter value in the database :

```
newCounterValue = counter + 1;
```

Comment: If done wrong, this will cause race conditions! You may not increment the counter in your code, but you should do it in your database code as some sort of atomic `UPDATE ... OUTPUT`.

Comment: Yes, your approach to increment the counter seems to be safer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Before trying your solution I have another question: is there en equivalent of a DataTable for Entity Framework to store the result of a raw query who retrive the max Id?

Comment: You are welcome. I'm not sure I've understood your question well. This is article how to get specific record : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016178/entity-framework-4-selecting-single-record , and this one how to update it (check the update part) http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=619