# Select a single object from Entity IQueryable List of object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a LINQ query statement shown below that queries an Entity Framework PersonalityType object from a SQL table. In the table there is a column with unique Ids(manually created) of personalities. Using Linq, I would like to make a selection of a single row PersonalityType object per query, therefore there is really no need to use the .ToList() or .ToArray() because there will always be a single match for the select.

```
    public enum Personality{Introvert = 0, Extrovert = 1, Agreeable = 2, Non-Agreeable = 3};
    var Personality = (from p in _ctx.PersonalityType.AsNoTracking()
    where (p.Id == (int) person.personality) // Personality Enum to int
    select new PersonalityTypeModel
    {
          PersonalityDescription = p.Description,
          HTMLContent = p.HTML
    }).ToArray();
```

How can I return a `PersonalityTypeModel` not a `List<PersonalityTypeModel>` from a Linq query?

Comment: if you want to retrieve single the you can use like `).SingleOrDefault();` or if you want to retrieve first then `).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 4: Selecting Single Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016178/entity-framework-4-selecting-single-record)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Sql table have single record per `PersonalityType` then you can use `).SingleOrDefault();` or `).FirstOrDefault();` like

```
var Personality = (from p in _ctx.PersonalityType.AsNoTracking()
where (p.Id == (int) person.personality)
select new PersonalityTypeModel
{
      PersonalityDescription = p.Description,
      HTMLContent = p.HTML
}).SingleOrDefault();   //FirstOrDefault()
```

So the query returns single object of `PersonalityTypeModel` instead of `List<PersonalityTypeModel>`.

**Note:**

If your Sql table contains more than one record with specific `PersonalityType` then you should use.

```
}).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

otherwise exception will be thrown. or you can simply use.

```
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You should note that if there is more than one `p.Id` in your table, it will throw an exception.

Comment: @SeM, that's why i described that `If your Sql table have single record per PersonalityType` in my answer but anyways i added one note also, and thanks for suggestion :)